# Fastest way of deleting a value in a comma separated list

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've got a list of names separated by commas (they may contain other characters), or be empty, but generally looking like this:

```
NameA,NameB,NameC
```

I need to create a function to delete a name if its present in the list and which restores the comma separated structure.

eg: if NameA is to be deleted, I should end up with:

```
NameB,NameC
```

NOT

```
,NameB,NameC
```

Similarly for the rest.

This is what I came up with, is there a better solution?

```
        $pieces = explode(",", $list);

        $key=array_search($deleteuser, $pieces);
        if(FALSE !== $key)
        {
            unset($pieces[$key]);
        }

        $list = implode(",", $pieces);
```

Comment: why do you need "fastest" way? Have any particular reason?

Comment: No, nothing in particular, but the explode/array_search/implode method seems slow...

Comment: Those methods are slow, since they are array operations. The string operations seem to be faster. See my answer below for a method that doesn't use array operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function to delete from the array. With offset = array_search($deleteuser, $pieces) and length = 1.

Comment: Why would `array_splice()` be any faster than using `unset()`?  It also looks like you are not taking care of the `false` vs `0` "gotcha".

Answer (score 2):

That should work pretty well. You may also be interested in PHP's fgetcsv function.
Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

If your application data is so large that you are experiencing a crippling amount of lag, then you may have bigger issues that this snippet of code.  It might be time to rethink your data storage and processing from the ground up.

In the meantime, here are some benchmarks when imploding a 5001 element array with commas, then using different techniques to remove value `4999`.  (speeds actually include the generation of the comma-separate string, but all benchmarks are identical in this regard)

- `explode()` + `array_search()` + `unset()` + `implode()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/6MuTj/perf#output))
  System time: ~.009 - .011s

  ```
    $pieces = explode(",", $list);
    if (($key = array_search($deleteuser, $pieces)) !== false) {
        unset($pieces[$key]);
    }
    echo implode(",", $pieces);
  ```

---

- `explode()` + `array_search()` + `array_splice()` + `implode()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/3Aq8q/perf#output))
  System time: ~.010 - .012s

  ```
    $pieces = explode(",", $list);
    if (($key = array_search($deleteuser, $pieces)) !== false) {
        array_splice($pieces, $key, 1);
    }
    echo implode(",", $pieces);
  ```

---

- `explode()` + `foreach()` + `if()` + `unset()` + `break` + `implode()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/IL8oP/perf#output))
  System time: ~.011 - .012s

  ```
    $pieces = explode(",", $list);
    foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $deleteuser) {
            unset($pieces[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    echo implode(",", $pieces);
  ```

(note: if you remove the `break`, the loop can remove multiple occurrences of the needle)

---

- `explode()` + `array_diff()` + `implode()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/Lqrae/perf#output))
  System time: ~.010 - .011s

  ```
    $pieces = explode(",", $list);
    $pieces = array_diff($pieces, [$deleteuser]);
    echo implode(",", $pieces);
    // or just: echo implode(',', array_diff(explode(",", $list), [$deleteuser]);
  ```

---

- `explode()` + `array_filter()` + `implode()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/JLj1c/perf#output))
  System time: ~.010 - .013s

  ```
    $pieces = explode(",", $list);
    $pieces = array_filter($pieces, function($v) use ($deleteuser) {
        return $v != $deleteuser;
    });
    echo implode(",", $pieces);
  ```

---

- `preg_quote()` + `preg_replace()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/K76Cl/perf#output)) ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LlRXYQ/1))
  System time: ~.007 - .010s

  ```
    $needle = preg_quote($deleteuser, '/');
    echo preg_replace('/,' . $needle . '(?=,|$)|^' . $needle . ',/', '', $list);
    // if replacing only one value, declare preg_replace's 4th parameter as 1
  ```

  Note that if you are using a delimiting character that has a special meaning to the regex engine (like `+`), then you will need to add a slash before it `\+` to escape it and make it literal.  This would make the pattern: `'/\+' . $needle . '(?=\+|$)|^' . $needle . '\+/'`

So while the regex-based snippet proved to be slightly (unnoticeably) faster for my arbitrarily conjured string length, you will need to make your own benchmarks to be sure which is the best performer for your application.

That said, and don't get me wrong I love regex, but the regular expression is going to be the easiest for developers to "get wrong" when it is time to modify the pattern AND I am confident that most devs will agree it has the worst overall comprehensibility.

Comment: Hi,

I am trying this with a plus sign instead of a comma. How to edit the last solution?

Comment: `$needle = preg_quote($deleteuser, '/');
  echo preg_replace('\+' . $needle . '(?=,|$)|^' . $needle . '\+', '', $list);`
This causes a warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: Okay, after reading your edit carefully, I found it: `preg_replace('/\+' . $needle . '(?=\+|$)|^' . $needle . '\+/', '', $list);`
Thank you ver much!

Answer (score -1):

You could also try a regular expression like this (maybe it can be optimized):

```
$search = 'NameB';
$list = 'NameA,NameB,NameC';
$list = preg_match('/(^' . $search . ',)|(,' . $search. ')/', '', $list);
```