# remove value(s) from a comma separated list from other value(s) from one other comma separated list

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare, array-difference

How can i remove value(s) from a comma separated list from other value(s) from one other comma separated list

I have this 2 array :

```
$users_list = '1, 2, 3';

$users_list_2  = '1, 2';
```

I would like to have this final result :

```
$final_users_list = '1,2';
```

I use

```
$final_users_list = array_diff($users_list, $users_list_2);
```

But the result is empty

I follow this example :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: In your example, $users_list and $users_list_2 are string not array. The array_diff function can't work with string.

Comment: in the array_diff or array_intersect you must use array and not string .. so you must convertn you string in proper array .. (and after rebuild the string)

Comment: yes, i’ve made a big mistake. I had before 2 arrays that i’ve converted in comma separated lists and I was completely mistaken.

Comment: Related: [Fastest way of deleting a value in a comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387450/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `$users_list`, and `$users_list_2` are **not** arrays. They are **strings**. To make'em arrays you need to `explode` these strings by `,`.

Second - to find elements that present in **both** arrays - use `array_intersect`.

Simplified final code is:

```
$users_list = '1, 2, 3';
$users_list_2  = '1, 2';
$final_users_list = array_intersect(
    explode(',', $users_list), 
    explode(',', $users_list_2)
);
echo'<pre>',print_r($final_users_list),'</pre>';
// or as a string 
echo implode(',', $final_users_list);
```

Finally, if you output arrays from `explode` with `var_dump` you will see that values of this arrays have spaces. These spaces can affect further comparison, so it's better to remove them with `array_map` and `trim` for example:

```
$users_list = '1, 2, 3';
$users_list_array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $users_list));

$users_list_2  = '1, 2';
$users_list_2_array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $users_list_2));

$final_users_list = array_intersect($users_list_array, $users_list_2_array);
echo'<pre>',print_r($final_users_list),'</pre>';
echo implode(',', $final_users_list);
```

Comment: I had before 2 arrays that i’ve converted in comma separated lists and I was completely mistaken. Your answer works like a charm.