# Remove 1st string from comma separated value

Tags: php

I want to remove 'array' string from below output

I have

```
<Charge enable="true">  
<stackholder name="name">1</stackholder>
<stackholder name="name">2</stackholder>
</Charge>
```

in my xml file to get all  number in stackholder tag I have done below code.

```
$calldata=json_decode(json_encode($row->Charge[0]->stackholder),true);
      $allcall = implode(',', $calldata);
```

my output is:

```
Array,1,2
```

but i want to remove 'Array' from output and output want to be
1,2

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP's JSON APIs, but the `Array` looks to be an artifact and not really part of your data.

Comment: Doing this via encoding-decoding as JSON seems like the wrong way to go about this in the first place here - IMHO that is an _abuse_ of those functions. You should simply loop over the `stackholder` nodes here, and add the content of each into an array while you are doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_search to get key and unset it

```
$calldata=json_decode(json_encode($row->Charge[0]->stackholder),true);
if (($key = array_search('Array', $calldata)) !== false) {
    unset($calldata[$key]);
}
 $allcall = implode(',', $calldata);
```

Comment: This advice can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387450/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

As if the Array keyword is only at first then use `unset`

```
calldata($arr[0]);
```

It deletes the element at corresponding key in an array.