# PHP remove values below a given value in a "|"-separated string

Tags: php

I have this value:

```
$numbers= "|800027|800036|800079|800097|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389"
```

And I want to remove the values below 800130 including the starting "|". I guess it is possible, but I can not find any examples anywhere. If anyone can point me to the right direction I would be thankful.

Comment: I don't see `800130` in a string. Am I blind?

Comment: `preg_split( '`|`' , $numbers , -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: @u_mulder presumably the OP meant that, for example, 800027 is less than 800130

Comment: Explode it, filter the array, implode it back.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: Related: [Fastest way of deleting a value in a comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387450/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the input string on pipe, then remove all array elements which, when cast to numbers, are less than `800130`.  Then, recombine to a pipe delimited string.

```php
$input= "|800027|800036|800079|800097|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389";
$input = ltrim($input, '|');
$numbers = explode("|", $input);
$array = [];
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number >= 800130) array_push($array, $number);
}
$output = implode("|", $array);
echo "|" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389
```

Comment: It is not printing "|" at the start.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well:

```
$numbers= "|800027|800036|800079|800097|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389";

function my_filter($value) {
    return ($value >= "800130");
}

$x = explode("|", $numbers);        // Convert to array
$y = array_filter($x, "my_filter"); // Filter out elements
$z = implode("|", $y);              // Convert to string again
echo $z;
```

Note that it's not necessary to have different variables (x,y,z). It's just there to make it a little bit easier to follow the code :)

Comment: It is not printing the first "|" at the start because explode makes the first array index as "".

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in function `preg_replace_callback` which takes a regular expression - in your case `\|(\d+)` - and applies a callback function to the matched values. Which means you can do this with a simple comparison of each matched value...

```
$numbers= "|800027|800036|800079|800097|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389";

echo preg_replace_callback("/\|(\d+)/", function($match){
    return $match[1] < 800130 ? "" : $match[0];
}, $numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split them with a regex and then filter the array.

```
$numbers= "|800027|800036|800079|800097|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389";
$below = '|'.join('|', array_filter(preg_split('/\|/', $numbers, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), fn($n) => $n < 800130));
```

```
|800027|800036|800079|800097
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` and `implode` functions and delete the values that are less than `80031`:

```
$numbers= "|800027|800036|800079|800097|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389";
$values = explode("|", $numbers);
for ($i=1;$i<sizeof($values);$i++) {
    if (intval($values[$i])<800130) {
        unset($values[$i]);
    }
}

// Notice I didn't start the $i index from 0 in the for loop above because the string is starting with "|", the first index value for explode is ""
// If you will not do this, you will get "|" in the end in the resulting string, instead of start.

$result = implode("|", $values);
echo $result;
```

It will print:

```
|800134|800215|800317|800341|800389
```